# Toggle one of two classes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am creating this button that expands when clicked and hides data when clicked again. I have made it work, but it was working only one time before refresh, then I figured I need to take a different approach, by toggling class on the button itself, not the div where data appears. And my problem is, that to do so I need to toggle only one of two classes the button has with javascript. How do I do that?

```
const expandMovies = document.querySelector("#btnMovies");
expandMovies.addEventListener("click", toggleMovies) 
function toggleMovies() {


if (expandMovies.classList.contains("inactive")) {

getMovies();
expandMovies.classList.toggle("active");

} else {
parentMovies.style.display="none";
expandMovies.classList.toggle("inactive");
}
};
```

Comment: You need to move the toggles outside the if - what I would say is why have both an active and inactive class - just set the default style for the button to be inactive and then override that with the actifve class styles - that way you can just toggle the active class

Answer (score 0):

You can use second property of toggle method which forces to remove  or add class forcibly. Following is the code snippet which can helpful for you.

```
const expandMovies = document.querySelector("#btnMovies");
expandMovies.addEventListener("click", toggleMovies) 
function toggleMovies() {


if (expandMovies.classList.contains("inactive")) {

getMovies();
expandMovies.classList.toggle("inactive",false);
expandMovies.classList.toggle("active",true);

} else {
parentMovies.style.display="none";
expandMovies.classList.toggle("active",false);
expandMovies.classList.toggle("inactive",true);
}
};
```